# How to apply Google Closure to my entire web page?

Tags: javascript, compression, google-closure-compiler

Google has the very nice JavaScript compressor called "Closure"

http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

But it's a pain to use for inline JavaScript within an HTML file.

Question: Does an online tool exist where I simply give the input "uncompress.html" and it spits out the compressed version of that HTML with all inline JavaScript compressed as well?

Comment: For what reasons do you need inline JavaScript within an HTML file?

Comment: I need the JS to run immediately. So the fasting performing way to do this is to have JS inline. Plus, this JS is only used on this one single HTML page

Answer (score 2):

Minifiers,obfuscators and compressors have been designed to solve the issue of downloading external elements when loading a page. They were never meant to be used for inline JavaScript or CSS since lots of that is normally kept outside of the page in a separate file.

Since you should be gzipping as much as you can, for browsers that can handle gzip, it shouldn't in reality matter that your inline css/javascript isn't minified on the page.

Comment: You would think but I have A LOT of JavaScript. Simply running Closure alone on my JS is reducing my JavaScript by nearly 94 kb even gzipped. My JavaScript approaching 400 kb (gzipped), so cutting 94 kb of gzipped JS is massive

Comment: if there is that much inline javascript it should probably be in its own file since it would have its own pipe for downloading and doesnt need to go into your all.js file. Modern browsers have 8 pipes for downloading so doubt you would have too much blocking

Comment: @NickH I'm pretty sure there's something terribly wrong going on with your development workflow. 400Kb of gzipped js is an order of magnitude bigger than jQuery itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHP, you might call the compiler of google in this way, and then use the header to return javascript

```
<?php
    $script = file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/scripts/script.js');
    $ch = curl_init('http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/compile');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'output_info=compiled_code&output_format=text&compilation_level=SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS&js_code=' . urlencode($script));
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    header('Content-type: application/javascript');
    echo $output;

?>
```

[link php code](http://bohuco.net/blog/2009/11/google-closure-compiler-with-php/)

Answer (score 0):

Mirroring AutomatedTester's comment, you really shouldn't put so much inline JavaScript into  your HTML file.

But if you really really want to do that for some reason, why can't you:

1. Make a text file containing the
   JavaScript
2. Compress it with
   Closure
3. Copy it into your
   `<script></script>` tag

I know this is not automatic, but you should only need to do this when you are deploying, and you are not deploying every hour, right?

I haven't seen much need to minimize HTML, since gzip typically does a good enough job...